# как передать данные из script в python?

Tags: python, html, backend

у меня есть следующий код

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Brython Examples</title>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython.js" integrity="sha256-rA89wPrTJJQFWJaZveKW8jpdmC3t5F9rRkPyBjz8G04=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.8/brython_stdlib.js" integrity="sha256-Gnrw9tIjrsXcZSCh/wos5Jrpn0bNVNFJuNJI9d71TDs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="brython()" id="test1">
    <div id="test1">
        <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter anything in mind">
    </div>
    <span id="output"></span>
        <script type="text/python" id="script1">
            from browser import document

            def show_text(e):
                document['output'].textContent = e.target.value;


            document['text'].bind('input', show_text)

        </script>
    </body>
```

Код ваводит данные полученые из формы на страницу (без нажатия кнопки submit и обновления страницы). Как передать полученные данные в views.py?
Заранее благодареню

Comment: Посмотри о протоколе WebSocket.